# Always end script before some hour

Tags: php, python, multithreading, cron

I looking-for solution to end script (can be written in PHP or Python) before some hour (eg. always before 2:00 at night). Script start (by `cron`) everyday at 0:00.

So, script should work max 2 hours.

But, everyday data is changed, will grow and script will need more time then 2 hours. Ofcourse script should parse whole data.

There is some solution to running this script in partials, mirrors, multithreading, calculation power of clouds?

Comment: You have two conflicting points in this question. You're asking for code that will stop your script after two hours, but every day it may need more than 2 hours.

Comment: @syntaqx I don't know how long my script will be work, but I would like to whole work should be end before 2:00 at nigtht.

Comment: What if it isn't finished? In any case, there could be many approaches, but first you must define which outcome is acceptable. And, as mentioned above, you currently have two conflicting requirements!

Comment: What if it isn't finished? In any case, there could be many approaches, but first you must define which outcome is acceptable. And, as mentioned above, you currently have two conflicting requirements!

Answer (score 0):

I think ultimately you're probably looking for PHP's [`set_time_limit($seconds)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function. With a little bit of math, you can set this up:

```
set_time_limit(2 * 60 * 60); // 2 (hours) * 60 (minutes) * 60 (seconds)
```

However, you'll need to be sure PHP can *actually* run this long by also ensuring your [`max_execution_time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) is also set to *at least* the same value.

In addition, setting these values in PHP does not necessarily override them from you `php.ini`. Depending on your environment, you will need to either set these values as well, or have the ability to set them from within a run time.

> **Note:** Be sure to check out the php.net comments about the way this functionality works, as it's not entirely transparent. For example, `sleep(n)` will be ignored in the execution time, and so your script will be `set_time_limit(n) + sleep(n)` runtime.